# Is there a way to open multiple files under different tabs in the same window in texshop?

Tags: texstudio, editors, texshop, preview

In TexShop everytime, I open a new file, it opens in a new window. A similar question has been asked before, but the solution is not there.  I have attached a snapshot of TexStudio to illustrate the nature of view I want. The files are displayed under different tabs.

[image]